# Java: is there more elegant way to extract a new list from an existing list using reduce?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, functional-programming, reducing

I'm trying to take a list of elements, make some manipulation on part of these elements and put the output of these manipulations in a new list. 
I want to do it with only one iteration on the list.

The only way I found to do it is:

```
List<Integer> newList = numList.stream().reduce(new ArrayList<Integer>(),
            (acc, value) -> {
                if (value % 2 == 0) {
                    acc.add(value * 10);
                }
                return acc;
            },
            (l1, l2) -> {
                l1.addAll(l2);
                return l1;
            }
        );
```

As you can see, it's very cumbersome.

I can of course use `filter` and then `map`, but in this case I iterate the list twice.

In other languages (Javascript for example) this kind of reduce operation is very straightforward, for example:

```
arr.reduce((acc, value) => { 
    if (value % 2 == 0) {
        acc.push(value * 10);
    }
    return acc;
}, new Array())
```

Amazing!
I was thinking to myself whether Java has some nicer version for this reduce or the Java code I wrote is the shortest way to do such an operation.

Comment: That’s not only cumbersome, it’s wrong. Reduction must not modify the input objects.

Answer (score 7):

> I can of course use filter and they map, but in this case I iterate the list twice.

That's not true. The elements of the `Stream` are iterated once, no matter how many intermediate operations you have.

Besides, the correct way to perform mutable reduction is to use `collect`:

```
List<Integer> newList =
    numList.stream()
            .filter(v -> v % 2 == 0)
            .map(v -> v * 10)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: OP wants _using reduce_

Comment: @HadiJ OP want a more elegant way. The more elegant (and correct) way is not to use reduce at all.

Comment: "The elements of the Stream are iterated once, no matter how many intermediate operations you have." - can you give me a link supporting that?

Comment: @CrazySynthax How about this : `The elements of a stream are only visited once during the life of a stream. Like an Iterator, a new stream must be generated to revisit the same elements of the source.` (source - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html)

Answer (score 2):

What you're doing is the opposite of functional programming, because you're using functions only to get a side effect.

You can simply not use reduce to make it even more explicit:

```
List<Integer> newList = numList.stream()
    .filter(value -> value % 2 == 0)
    .map(value -> value * 10)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Edit: `Stream`s iterate over the collection once by definition. According to the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html):

> A stream should be operated on (invoking an intermediate or terminal stream operation) only once.

Comment: OP wants _using reduce_

Comment: Sure! But this attitude has a penalty of iterating the list twice, and I want only one iteration.

Comment: @HadiJ OP didn't want to iterate over the collection twice, this way it doesn't

Comment: @CrazySynthax why do you think so? There is only a single iteration over the collection, that's the `Stream`'s definition